# Spring Data JPA OneToOne entity not found

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring-boot 1.2.1, with Spring-Data-JPA and Hibernate.  I have a simple OneToOne mapping that saves the entities properly, but when I try and GET the value, it fails because it can't find the child entity.

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OPERATORY")
public class Operatory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long operatoryId;

    private Long officeId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,optional=false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="employeeId", referencedColumnName="employeeId",nullable=false)
    private Employee employee;

..
}
```

That contains a unidirectional reference to this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long employeeId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "officeId", nullable = false)
    private Office office;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private User user;  <== this works and its the same relationship type
     ...
}
```

I am using a JPA Repository:

```
public interface OperatoryRepository  extends CrudRepository<Operatory, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Operatory> {

    public List<Operatory> findAll(Predicate predicate);

    public List<Operatory> findByOfficeId(Long office);
}
```

I have this in the db:

```
**Operatory**

operatory_id  | office_id | employee_id | name
1             |      1    |       1     | Test One
```

**Employee**

```
employee_id  | office_id |.....
1            |     1     | ...
```

When I try and find the operatory for that office, associated with an exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find Employee with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Employee with id 1
```

Here is the Hibernate logging I receive:

```
Hibernate: select operatory0_.operatory_id as operator1_18_, operatory0_.employee_id as employee4_18_, operatory0_.name as name2_18_, operatory0_.office_id as office_i3_18_ from operatory operatory0_ where operatory0_.office_id=?
Hibernate: select employee0_.employee_id as employee1_5_0_, employee0_.address_id as address17_5_0_, employee0_.begin_date as begin_da2_5_0_, employee0_.contact_id as contact_3_5_0_, employee0_.end_date as end_date4_5_0_, employee0_.first_name as first_na5_5_0_, employee0_.full_name as full_nam6_5_0_, employee0_.gender as gender7_5_0_, employee0_.last_name as last_nam8_5_0_, employee0_.license_number as license_9_5_0_, employee0_.masked_ssn as masked_10_5_0_, employee0_.office_id as office_18_5_0_, employee0_.portrait_image_location as portrai11_5_0_, employee0_.prefix_id as prefix_12_5_0_, employee0_.schedule_id as schedul13_5_0_, employee0_.specialty_id as special19_5_0_, employee0_.ssn as ssn14_5_0_, employee0_.status as status15_5_0_, employee0_.suffix_id as suffix_16_5_0_, employee0_.username as usernam20_5_0_, address1_.address_id as address_1_0_1_, address1_.address_line1 as address_2_0_1_, address1_.address_line2 as address_3_0_1_, address1_.address_line3 as address_4_0_1_, address1_.address_type as address_5_0_1_, address1_.begin_date_time as begin_da6_0_1_, address1_.city as city7_0_1_, address1_.end_date_time as end_date8_0_1_, address1_.state as state9_0_1_, address1_.status as status10_0_1_, address1_.zip as zip11_0_1_, office2_.office_id as office_i1_11_2_, office2_.address_id as address11_11_2_, office2_.begin_date as begin_da2_11_2_, office2_.ein as ein3_11_2_, office2_.end_date as end_date4_11_2_, office2_.language_id as language5_11_2_, office2_.name as name6_11_2_, office2_.office_type as office_t7_11_2_, office2_.owner_id as owner_i12_11_2_, office2_.service_package_type as service_8_11_2_, office2_.status as status9_11_2_, office2_.service_package_id as service13_11_2_, office2_.url as url10_11_2_, address3_.address_id as address_1_0_3_, address3_.address_line1 as address_2_0_3_, address3_.address_line2 as address_3_0_3_, address3_.address_line3 as address_4_0_3_, address3_.address_type as address_5_0_3_, address3_.begin_date_time as begin_da6_0_3_, address3_.city as city7_0_3_, address3_.end_date_time as end_date8_0_3_, address3_.state as state9_0_3_, address3_.status as status10_0_3_, address3_.zip as zip11_0_3_, officecont4_.office_id as office_i7_11_4_, officecont4_.office_contact_id as office_c1_13_4_, officecont4_.office_contact_id as office_c1_13_5_, officecont4_.begin_date as begin_da2_13_5_, officecont4_.contact_info as contact_3_13_5_, officecont4_.contact_type as contact_4_13_5_, officecont4_.end_date as end_date5_13_5_, officecont4_.office_id as office_i7_13_5_, officecont4_.status as status6_13_5_, owner5_.owner_id as owner_id1_19_6_, owner5_.begin_date as begin_da2_19_6_, owner5_.end_date as end_date3_19_6_, owner5_.first_name as first_na4_19_6_, owner5_.last_name as last_nam5_19_6_, owner5_.name as name6_19_6_, owner5_.owner_type as owner_ty7_19_6_, owner5_.prefix_id as prefix_i8_19_6_, owner5_.status as status9_19_6_, owner5_.suffix_id as suffix_10_19_6_, specialty6_.specialty_id as specialt1_28_7_, specialty6_.description as descript2_28_7_, specialty6_.title as title3_28_7_, user7_.username as username1_31_8_, user7_.account_non_expired as account_2_31_8_, user7_.account_non_locked as account_3_31_8_, user7_.credentials_non_expired as credenti4_31_8_, user7_.enabled as enabled5_31_8_, user7_.office_id as office_i8_31_8_, user7_.password as password6_31_8_, user7_.authority as authorit7_31_8_, office8_.office_id as office_i1_11_9_, office8_.address_id as address11_11_9_, office8_.begin_date as begin_da2_11_9_, office8_.ein as ein3_11_9_, office8_.end_date as end_date4_11_9_, office8_.language_id as language5_11_9_, office8_.name as name6_11_9_, office8_.office_type as office_t7_11_9_, office8_.owner_id as owner_i12_11_9_, office8_.service_package_type as service_8_11_9_, office8_.status as status9_11_9_, office8_.service_package_id as service13_11_9_, office8_.url as url10_11_9_ from employee employee0_ inner join address address1_ on employee0_.address_id=address1_.address_id inner join office office2_ on employee0_.office_id=office2_.office_id inner join address address3_ on office2_.address_id=address3_.address_id left outer join officecontact officecont4_ on office2_.office_id=officecont4_.office_id left outer join owner owner5_ on office2_.owner_id=owner5_.owner_id inner join specialty specialty6_ on employee0_.specialty_id=specialty6_.specialty_id inner join users user7_ on employee0_.username=user7_.username inner join office office8_ on user7_.office_id=office8_.office_id where employee0_.employee_id=?
```

changing the @OneToOne to from EAGER to LAZY just postpones the exception.  I see the values in the database.  But I cannot figure out why the Employee cannot be found from the Operatory.

Comment: Looks like your `@JoinColumn` is wrong. should be `employee_id` and not `employeeId` same for 'officeId`.

Comment: I changed both name and referencedColumnName to "employee_id" and I get the startup exception `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: employee_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(employee)`  Removing the referencedColumnName from @JoinColumn allows startup, but the EntityNotFoundException still occurs.

Comment: There's something weird in your Employee entity, maybe just formatting of the question, but might be worth fixing up: `property = "employeeId")`

Comment: sorry, that was copy & paste error from my @JsonIdentityInfo that isn't in this post.

Comment: Can you turn on logging off the sql hibernate generated?

Comment: I updated the question with the logging.  I am not very good at reading those, so hopefully it makes more sense to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query fetches the `employee` by `employee_id` but there are also a number of `inner join` of other entities/tables (some of which are not shown in the code you posted), i.e. `address` joined to `employee`, `office` joined to `employee`, `address` joined to `office`, `specialty` joined to `employee`, `users` joined to `employee` and finally `office` joined to `user`. If any of these relationships is missing in your data, the query will not return your `employee`, even though you see it in the `employee` table.

This is the relavant part of the second hibernate query you posted slightly reformatted:

> inner join address address1_ on employee0_.address_id=address1_.address_id
>   inner join office office2_ on employee0_.office_id=office2_.office_id
>   inner join address address3_ on office2_.address_id=address3_.address_id
>   inner join specialty specialty6_ on employee0_.specialty_id=specialty6_.specialty_id
>   inner join users user7_ on employee0_.username=user7_.username
>   inner join office office8_ on user7_.office_id=office8_.office_id

Comment: Thank you ci_ for the explanation.  As hibernate builds this query for me, I guess there isn't much I can do other than tweak my relationships so null values in office  (for example), don't affect something else.

Comment: You could make it "optional" if it is.